# Should I prefer ContextCompat or PermissionChecker for permission checking on Android?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I can choose from either of the following ways of checking to see if my app has a given permission.

Which one is preferred?

`ContextCompat` (from `support-compat` lib):

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```

Or `PermissionChecker` (from `support-core-utils` lib):

```
PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```

Note that (as of 25.3.1) -core-utils depends on -compat:

`|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)`

Comment: Personally, I use `ContextCompat`. I have no reason for choosing that over `PermissionChecker`, but I have had no problems yet.

Comment: Agreed. I have seen no need for `PermissionChecker`, and frankly the documentation for it sucks.

Comment: I read through the source and learned a few things. Looks like `ContextCompat` is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Stepping into the source of `PermissionChecker` we can see that it first calls through to [`Context#checkPermission`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkPermission(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) and bails early if the calling code does *not* have permission. If the calling code does have permission it then goes to the mysterious [`AppOpsManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager.html) asking if we have [`permissionToOp`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager.html#permissionToOp(java.lang.String)), followed by a check against the return of [`noteProxyOp`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager.html#noteProxyOp(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). This gives us a hint about what this method is for, since the docs for `noteProxyOp` start with:

> Make note of an application performing an operation on behalf of another application when handling an IPC.

Additionally, if we check the return value of the `PermissionChecker` method we see we get back one of 3 possible results:

> The permission check result which is either `PERMISSION_GRANTED` or `PERMISSION_DENIED` or `PERMISSION_DENIED_APP_OP`.

That is, 0, -1 or -2 return values. This class appears to be intended for use by apps receiving inter-process communication and performing actions on behalf of other apps.

`ContextCompat` on the other hand, simply grabs the current process ID and directly returns the result of `Context#checkPermission`:

> `PERMISSION_GRANTED` if the given pid/uid is allowed that permission, or `PERMISSION_DENIED` if it is not.

So for most developers writing standard Android apps, **use `ContextCompat`**.

Answer (score 3):

I will go with `ContextCompat` because of documentation and quality of tutorials available
But I have read somewhere the following:
If your device is running on Android M and higher and targetSdkVersion is below 22, there is a slight difference between the two.
When you launch the application the first time with the device permission set to off, the behaviors are as follows:

1. ContextCompat : Always returns GRANTED
2. PermissionChecker : Returns GRANTED or PERMISSION_DENIED_APP_OP

With this using `PermissionChecker` might be wiser, but again to implement runtime permissions, you need to set your targetSdkVersion to 23 and higher.

Comment: If you get `PERMISSION_DENIED_APP_OP` and your compileSdk is 22 or lower, your code likely doesn't even consider that as a possibility - that constant was added in SDK 23.

Comment: You say that if you have compileSdk 22 and you call ContextCompat you always get `GRANTED` the _first_ time (even if the user has disabled access). Do you then get `DENIED` in subsequent calls? Even though you've declared the permission in your manifest and don't "know" about granular permissions (and should therefore always have permission - I realise it just no-ops when you call APIs that have been denied)? I'll do some testing on this.

Comment: @AdamS
Sorry like I said , I read somewhere. I haven't checked the validity yet.
Here is the source which is unfortunately in Japanese.
http://sys1yagi.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/11/07/185539

Comment: This sort of trailed off, but what this means is that for compileSDK 22 or lower, the permission is checked on installation, not runtime. First or subsequent calls should be irrelevant, as if the user has installed the app, he has accepted the permission already, hence it always would return GRANTED.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr: use `ContextCompat` as docs and tuts suggesting most oftenly!!**

Yet another example, when `PermissionChecker` isn't working reliable and returns (probably) `PERMISSION_DENIED_APP_OP`, at least `!=PERMISSION_GRANTED`: asking `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`/`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and getting not what we wanted exacly (location data access always when location turned on)...

1. [Android 10 introduced limited background access](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#app-access-device-location), when app is killed it doesn't have permission (yep, that might be a problem for some!),
2. [Android 11 made it harder to gain it](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/location#background-location)
3. [Android 12 allowed user to grant only coarse location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#approximate-request) even when app may need fine/precise data, also added new options like "While using app" or "Only this time".
4. [`targetSdk` makes the difference](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#background-dialog-target-sdk-version)

Some of mixes of these dialogs resolutions and `targetSdk` param of app (before/after "new way" appeared in API) won't be treated by `PermissionChecker` as "really granted"

e.g. when app `targetSdk=30` (before above API "improvements") request `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and "while using app" then `PermissionChecker` won't return `PERMISSION_GRANTED`. `ContextCompat` will and thats true, we have access to (fine) location then